# Reinstall Ubuntu 11.10 in Windows 7 without formatting the HD

Tags: windows, installation, ubuntu-11.10, reinstall

I have a laptop with Windows 7. Sometime ago, I tried to install Ubuntu using the cd and clicking the option "Install with Windows", however it never worked, never finished the installation. Now I am trying to install it again. I know how to make partitions and format them using Linux Command Line, but only with "empty" drives. Now, I have lots of information in my HD. When I insert the CD, Ubuntu displays the message "Multiple Operating Systems detected" which leads to two options: "Erase everything and install Ubuntu" or "Use the partition manager", when I see the manager I only see two partitions, one is very small (sda1 like 512 Mb) and the big one (sd2 = 318 Gb). As far as I know, I would need to erase Ubuntu's bootloader. My question is, How can I install Ubuntu using "Install with Windows" options instead of manually making partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best: ***Use Ubuntu in virtual box***. What is your computer specifications? In the current scenario, you might risk loosing data so before you do anything, please make a backup of your drives. I'd suggest you provide us with screen shots so we can look at the problem in more detail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wubi installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer), which will let you install Ubuntu in and alongside Windows.

> Wubi is an officially supported Ubuntu installer for Windows users. It can install and uninstall Ubuntu in the same way as any other Windows application. It's simple and safe.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it! Then I will use Virtual Box, just to be safe. Thanks!